# Sending mail to multiple users of specific group, odoo12

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo-12

I have an email template which is sent whenever a new record is created. This email is sent to only one person as I have specified only one email id in the email_to field.

I have also created a custom group for users only. I wanted to send an email notification to all the users of the users' group by checking if email id is present or not iteratively after the new record is created. How can I get email id of users from users' group in email_to field in email template and sent automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your mail template

```
<field name="email_to">${object.get_email_to()}</field>
```

python method like this

```
@api.model
def get_email_to(self):
    user_group = self.env.ref("res.group_res_user")
    email_list = [
        usr.partner_id.email for usr in user_group.users if usr.partner_id.email]
    return ",".join(email_list)
```

hope this is working well with your requirement..

Comment: How can I get email id of all the users who are part of the users' group? I am trying but it takes only one email_id. Is there any way to get the email of all the users of the specific group.

Answer (score 1):

first you overwrite your model create method like this..

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
    template = self.env.ref('module_name.template_id')
    template.send_mail(res.id, force_send=True)
    return res
```

it will send the mail from create new record. You can define the to_email in mail template that you want from record..

Comment: But how can I get email_to of various users from a specific group?

Comment: how can I locate which email template to be sent from this code?

Comment: sry, it was my mistake i am edit the code for the template selection

Comment: and to_email is getting with the simple method writing on to the same model

Answer (score 0):

First create a field(change field name according to you):

```py
student_mail=fields.Char(compute="get_email_to")
```

After than declare a function:

```
def get_email_to(self):
    mail_id= self.env['school.management'].search([])

    filter_mail = [i.email for i in mail_id if i.college_id]
    self.student_mail=",".join(filter_mail)
    result=",".join(filter_mail)
    self.student_mail=result.replace('"','')
```

And in XML:

```html
<field name="email_to">${object.student_mail}</field>
```

In my case I filter student base on college id...